# Retrieve the Supplier details using FEI number?

Tags: openfda

a. Can we retrieve the Supplier details using FEI number, in any of the APIs? 
b. Are there any datasets or APIs available to query information under Cosmetics?
c. Are there any open APIs to fetch data available in the below URL https://datadashboard.fda.gov/ora/fd/fser.htm

Answer (score 0):

As far as openFDA is concerned, the answer would be no.

Comment: Thanks for the response Denis Krylov. So would you know if there is any mechanism (other than data mining) to retrieve this data?

Comment: Not that I know of. My apologies.